# Comparing a file on disk and its corresponding version on Head?

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

How would I go about taking a diff between a file on a disk and its corresponding version on the HEAD?

I've tried:

```
TreeChanges changes = repo.Diff.Compare(repo.Head.Tip.Tree, DiffTarget.Index);
```

`DiffTarget.Index` only diffs changes between the Index and the Head's tree. This is fine, but I also want a way to retrieve changes between working copy and tree. Is this possible?

And how could I limit the diff only to a certain file -- no the entire Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also want a way to retrieve changes between working copy and tree.

This is still being worked on. However, you can get a first peek of the API **[here](https://github.com/nulltoken/libgit2sharp/tree/topic/more-diff)**.

> How could I limit the diff only to a certain file -- no the entire Index?

Libgit2 **[exposes a way](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/diff.h#L56-63)** to restrict the scope of the diff to the content of an array of paths. This hasn't been wrapped yet in LibGit2Sharp.

Comment: Is the path support in an issue ticket yet?

Comment: I don't think so. Feel free to add one :)